# How can I communication between master page and site pages?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have a master page of SharePoint and in the master page I try to retrieve some data from the list and show them in the site pages that use the master page I mentioned before.

But the question is that when I try to store the data I retrieved in the master page to the hidden field, I can not get the latest updated datas. Instead of using hidden field, I try to use the cookie (a kind of jquery plugin) to store the data and get them in the site pages. But I also can't get the latest data.

At last, I found the question: the site pages' `document.ready()` method is invoked before the master page's `document.ready()` method, so I always get the old data even though the page postback.

Can I have any better way to communicate between master page and site pages?

Or are there any method to make sure that the master page's document.ready() method is invoked before site pages' document.ready()?

I have found a ugly way to solve this problem: I use the `setTimeout("getTabTips()",1000);`to make the site pages' `document.ready()`invoke after master page's .But acturally,it did not works so perfect! I really want to find a beautiful answer to this question, please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and after some research I came to the same conclusion: use cookies. I wrapped it in a little class called `LocalConnection`: https://github.com/jeremyharris/local_connection

LocalConnection uses callbacks so its syntax should be pretty familiar. Since it uses callbacks, you could even set up a callback to tell the master that the other pages are ready.

**Master**

```
var c = new LocalConnection({
  name: 'mycookiename'
});
// start listening
c.listen();
c.addCallback('ready', function(pageId) {
  // sub page ready
});
```

**SubPage**

```
var c = new LocalConnection({
  name: 'mycookiename'
});
// start listening
c.listen();
$(document).ready(function() {
  c.send('ready', 'somePageId');
});
```

With LocalConnection this isn't entirely necessary. Events are queued up and fired when the receivers get read the cookie, so the Master could "fire events" and the receiver page would trigger them when they open.

Comment: I used `setTimeout()` to delay the invokation of site pages' `document.ready()` ,and the problem is gone. But it not works so fine, even a little clumsy. So I'm tring to find a better way here ...

Comment: My example above using LocalConnection would tell your master page when your subpages were ready. Did you give it a shot?

Comment: It's really handsome .I will use it in my company's sharepoint project. Thks a millious.